# Azure Data Factory Read Csv Files from multiple portioned folders

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to read csv file from partitioned folders using dataflow activity ((yyyy/mm/dd/timestamp). how to read the csv files dynamically?

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to read single short for all the sub folders? above folder structure before start YYYY (year), the table name as a folder path.

eg : test/dwh/tablename/2023/01/15/100543/files.csv

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Wildcard paths** in source options in dataflow as below.
`test/dwh/tablename/**/**/**/**/*.csv`

[image]

Here, you can give the **Partition root path**, that tablename in your case.

In my case following is the path
`sampletable/2022/01/12/102344/part1.csv`
In each csv files there are `6627` records.

And this is the number of rows written.

[image].

Comment: can you share your dataset linked service path

Comment: i hope, there is year under each month and date separate timestamp folder having csv file, if we give the wildcard path, the data loaded all the files. if i am wrong, please let me know

Comment: how do we give datasets path, i can give until  "test/dwh/tablename" ?

Comment: my linked service path is container storage. Just `sampletable`. So i given wildcard path as above. Can you share me your linked service path? is it `tablename`?

Comment: first three three folder followed by next folder name is tablename then we have year as folder and sub sequent folder month and date then final folder is timestam *.csv file
example container(test)/subfolder(dwh)/subfolder(LM)/tablename(folder)/2023/

Comment: under 2023/ i have many folder like month wise and each month I have a date folder and each date folder i have a time(like 100345)..final each time folder, I have one or more csv files

Comment: eg: test/dwh/LM/tablename/2023/01/30/100354/*.csv files, how do we use dataset for the path and wildcard and root path

Comment: you need to read all files under tablename right?. what is the linked service path you given?

Comment: [This documentation may help you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#source-transformation)
Better test with smaller dataset, because the data preview may fail even though you set row limit.

Comment: my dataset path test/dwh/LM/tablename/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253310/discussion-between-jayashankargs-and-developer-ke).